# VBA to export excel tasks into MS Project

Tags: vba, excel, ms-project

I'm currently trying to create code that will allow myself, and other users of the excel workbook I create, to export tasks, start dates and finish dates from Excel to MS Project. 
I've tried a number of ways, without much success.

I've seen that you can simply create and save a map between Excel and Project - however, this will only work for one user. Is there a way to export a map so that all users can use the same map? e.g. saving the map on a shared drive, and getting the code to import tasks into Project using that mapping?

I'm currently saving the Excel output I need to export under the headings the mapping creates:

`ID,    Outline_Level,  Name,   Start_Date, Finish_Date.`

I've also seen that it is possible to add a task in Project using VBA from Excel. However, I could not find a way to state the start date and finish date. Ideally, I would like a macro in Excel which reads down a list of tasks, and adds them one by one into MS Project, exporting the Start and Finish dates.
I know it would be quicker to do this all in one go, but I will not be using it for a huge array of tasks per project.

Any help is well received! Thanks in advance!